# Link_to Show Action in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In my `index.html.erb` file, I have:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', post %>
<% end %>
```

How can I link_to the show action but having the `<%= post.title =>` as the name of the link?

I've tried `<%= link_to '<%= post.title %>', post %>` but it doesn't work. Am I missing something or do I need to change something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%= link_to post.title, post %>
```

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: I will when it lets me :) I have to wait 8 mins

Answer (score 1):

this wil help:

```
 <%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %>.
```

Also you should read this: [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)